# How to run Espresso tests with specific annotation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

For example, I would like to run all tests with annotation @FlakyTest.

```
@Test
@FlakyTest
fun sampleTest() {
    onView(...)
}
```

And there are many other tests with @FlakyTest in my code.

I can do this from the command line as this https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner says.

Filter test run to tests with given annotation: `adb shell am instrument -w -e annotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

I know how to run just one test in Android Studio by clicking the green play button next to it or from creating a Run/Debug configuration with test field as "Method". But there is no selection to run for a specific annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your specific annotation as an argument to the instrumentation arguments by editing the run configuration as described by the Android team [**here**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/benchmarking/macrobenchmark-instrumentation-args)

Check the following screenshot example:
[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVVO2.png)

Also, you can achieve the same thing via a command line:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -P android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation=com.example.test.YourAnnotation
```